# Server-side application configuration security. Best practices

Tags: .net, security, configuration

We publish server-side application to our customer workstation and customer's security guys are concerned about configuration connection strings safety.

Connection strings are stored as plain text right now, but as configuration file is not in the public/shared folder we supposed that workstation security itself is enough.

What are the ways to improve connection strings security further?

It is a big step forward to encrypt password and keep a decryption key on the same workstation? What are the steps we can take to keep connection strings (and alike) information more and more securable?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why do you need to protect connection strings? If you store there user credentials then may be it is better to use "Integrated Security" (if possible)..? In addition you could restrict user rights on database level.

But if you're sure that you really need to encrypt something in config then [check this](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/protecting-connection-strings-and-other-configuration-information-cs)

Comment: Thank you for the refference but I wonder if encryption really increases safety? As decryption key is stored in machine.config it costs nothing to take app.config/web.config with machine.config for a hacker and decode encrypted configuration sections. Does machine.config access is more restricted for some reason then app.config access?

Comment: if your application runs under identity with restricted rights (or lets say "properly configured") then this user won't have permission to read root machine.config (ie, exploiting your app is useless). Of course, user with admin rights can steal both files